# Getting an error message while compiling a Java Connection Pool Class

Tags: java, connection-pooling

i made a package name **mybundle**. Inside this, i have a java file named **DBConnectionManager.java**. I am trying to compile this file but it gives an error message.

**DBConnectionManager.java**

```
package mybundle;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DBConnectionManager{

private String qry, driver, db, msg;

private Vector connectionPool; 

public DBConnectionManager(){

    this.connectionPool = new Vector();

    driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
    db = "jdbc:odbc:db";
    initialize();
}
private void initialize(){
    initializeConnectionPool();
}
private String initializeConnectionPool(){
    while(!checkIfConnectionPoolIsFull()){
        connectionPool.addElement(createNewConnectionForPool());
    }
    msg = "Connection Pool is full..";
    return msg;
}
private boolean checkIfConnectionPoolIsFull(){
    final int MAX_POOL_SIZE = 5;

    if(connectionPool.size() < 5){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
} 
private Connection createNewConnectionForPool(){
    Connection connection = null;
    try{
        Class.forName(driver);
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
    }catch(Exception ex){}
    return connection;
}
public Connection getConnectionFromPool(){
    Connection connection = null;
    if(connectionPool.size() > 0){
        connection = (Connection)connectionPool.firstElement();
        connectionPool.removeElementAt(0); 
    }
    return connection;
}
public void returnConnectionToPool(Connection connection){
    connectionPool.addElement(connection);

}}
```

**This is where i have placed Tomcat, JDK1.5 and my package mybndle**

My jdk1.5 and tomcat are in:

D:\java\jdk1.5

D:\java\tomcat

D:\java\mybundle

**This is how i am compiling DBConnectionManager.java file**

D:\java\mybundle>set path=d:\java\jdk1.5\bin

D:\java\mybundle>javac DBConnectionManager.java

**I am getting this error message**

```
D:\>cd java

D:\Java>cd mybundle

D:\Java\mybundle>set path=d:\java\jdk1.5\bin

D:\Java\mybundle>javac DBConnectionManager.java

Note: DBConnectionManager.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

D:\Java\mybundle>
```

I am trying too hard to figure out what is wrong but, in vain. Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: this is warning not error. but its better to use `ArrayList` instead of `Vector`

Comment: Thanks **@vels4j**. Let me try ArrayList.

Comment: did you Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details?

Comment: **@Sura** i tried but no use.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a `Vector` (ew), which is genericized, but not providing a type.

You likely want `Vector<Connection>` if you're insistent on using a `Vector`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html

That said, why write your own connection pool?

Comment: thanks **@Dave Newton**. I am new to java. I've given a task to make connection pool class for jsp page. I do have a code of it but i do not know how it works. For my understanding, i wrote this my own class so that i can understand well each and every step. I have to connect Ms Access database actually. I googled but did not get any idea.